# How to set the cover for custom album in iOS Photos?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller, alassetslibrary

This [article](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/) is a great tutorial for creating custom photo album. However, it only sets the first photo as the album cover. I would like to set the latest saved photo as cover, just like the Camera Roll. Is there any API to do that?

Answer (score 3):

There is no custom method to do that. The album cover is set automatically and represents the last photo assigned to the album.

Comment: How can you set the last photo as album cover? Would you please share your code?

Comment: This is done automatically. Each time you add a new photos to an album, it becomes the album cover.

Comment: The Camera Roll's album cover is done automatically, but the custom album is not that case. If you have installed the latest Path app, you can see the Path album cover will not change.

Comment: For custom albums created on the device the cover picture is always the first photo added to the album. It doesn't change if you add more photos and there is no method to change it.

Answer (score 2):

Go into the iOS album you want to set the cover picture. Long press on the image you want to set as cover and slide it (move it) to make it the first picture of the album. That first picture is going to be the cover picture of the album.

Comment: But I want to maintain a certain order of photos in my album